# Polymer force narrow forceNarrow is not working

Tags: polymer

I am trying to use forcedNarrow=true with paper-drawer-panel. But my page is not responding. Here is my code. Apparently none of the other API are also working. Is there any solution to this problem? I have tried restructuring my web page. But the feature it seems cannot be accessed.

```
<paper-drawer-panel forcedNarrow='true'>

    <paper-header-panel main navigation flex>

        <paper-toolbar id='mytoolbar'>
 <div id='company_name'>KURIER  </div>
</paper-toolbar>

        <paper-toolbar id='secondary'>
            <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle on-tap="menuAction" ></paper-icon-button>
            <paper-button raised>Login</paper-button>"
            <paper-button raised>Sign Up</paper-button>
        </paper-toolbar>



            <div id='signup'>
                <form method="get" action="{% url 'transport:index' %}">
                    <label for="i-want">I Want</label>
                    <input type="text" name="item-url" id="i-want">
                    <input type="submit" value="I want">
                </form>

                <form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post" action="{% url 'transport:signup' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    Sign Up
                    <paper-input label="Username" name="username-signup" id="username-signup"></paper-input>
                    <paper-input label="Password" type="password" name="password-signup" id="password-signup"></paper-input>
                    <paper-input label="Verify Password" type="password" name="password-verify" id="password-verify"></paper-input>
                    <paper-input label="Email" type="email" name="email-signup" id="email-signup"></paper-input>
                    <paper-input label="First Name" name="first_name-signup" id="firstname-signup"></paper-input>
                    <paper-input label="Last Name" name="last_name-signup" id="lastname-signup"></paper-input>
                    <paper-input label="Address 1" name="address_st_1" id="address1"></paper-input>
                    <paper-input label="Address 2/District" name="address_st_2" id="address2"></paper-input>
                    <paper-input label="Phone Number" name="phone_number" id="phone_number"></paper-input>
                    <paper-input label="City" name="city" id="city"></paper-input>
                    <paper-input label="State" name="state" id="state"></paper-input>
                    <paper-input label="Zip Code" name="zip_code" id="zip_code"></paper-input>
                    <paper-input label="Country" name="country" id="country"></paper-input>
                    <paper-button raised onclick="submitForm()">Sign Up</paper-button>
                </form>
            </div>
    </paper-header-panel>

    <div drawer>
    <paper-button>Login</paper-button>
    </div>

</paper-drawer-panel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's `forceNarrow`, not `forcedNarrow`. See [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-drawer-panel).
2. Camelcase attributes are written as hyphen separated attributes when composing an element, `<paper-drawer-panel force-narrow>`

Comment: Sorry I did use forcedNarrow

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the answer is `<paper-drawer-panel force-Narrow>`